# Google Console API OAuth ID creator keeps thinking my packagename and fingerprint pair is not unique

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-api-console

Google Console API seem to corrupt my account. I am trying to recreate a OAuth Client ID with a specific package name and a production keystore. But it keeps saying that "This client ID is globally unique and is already in use".

I have actually created a client ID with the same combination setting before in production project. But for testing purposes, I deleted it and added in a different project. Then after testing, I deleted and added it back into the production project, and then it stopped letting me add it back in.

Some people have mention that they have been able to get in contact with Google to fix it. But I haven't found their contact details.

Comment: best way is to contact their support,they will solve your problem

Comment: I can't seem to find their support details for specifically to console api problems. All of them just link me to more FAQs. And I have posted on so many google forums and have got no response

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into this.
For others, client ID are not designed to be deleted and created again and again. Once an app is published or the client ID is in production you don't want to edit that client id again.